# Custom module, checking variable in observer

Tags: magento2, module, event-observer, view

I'm new in making modules, considering below code wondering how would be possible to verify if the checkbox has been selected:

my observer.php:

```
public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );
            if (???) {
                // do this if checbox is selected
            } else {

                // do this if not selected
        }
}
```

my viewfile.phtml

```
<?php

/** @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View */
?>
<?php $_product = $block->getProduct(); ?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable()):?>      
        <div id="rent>
           <input id="my_checkbox" type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Rent">I want to rent this product        
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        require([
            'jquery'
        ], function ($) {
            $(document).ready(function () {
                if($('#my_checkbox').prop('checked')) {
                    //checkbox is checked
                } else {
                    //checkbox is NOT checked
                }
            });
        }

        });
    </script>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: which event are you observing ?

Comment: If your are observing save event than you can get data from $_POST object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check inside **observer.php** file,

```
<?php

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer) {
        $item=$observer->getEvent()->getData('quote_item');
        $product=$observer->getEvent()->getData('product');
        $item = ( $item->getParentItem() ? $item->getParentItem() : $item );

        if(isset($_POST['vehicle']) && $_POST['vehicle'] == 'Rent') 
        {
            echo "Checkbox value";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Not selected";
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface` to get the param.

```
protected $_request;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
)
{
    $this->_request = $request;
}

public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
{
    $vehicle = $this->_request->getParam('vehicle');
    //Check the condition here

}
```